# Generating Metro Client Using Local WSDL File

Tags: wsdl, java-metro-framework, wsimport

I have generated a Metro client using wsimport before, but in that case the WSDL was accessed over https.  My commaned looked like this:

```
wsimport https://service.net/services/Service?wsdl -d C:\ClientProject\src\main\java -keep
```

and everything worked fine. Now I am trying to generate a client, however, I only have a local copy of the WSDL file. My project directory is set up like this (in c:\Devel):

```
ClientProject
  |- src
     |- main
        |- java
     |- resources
        |- META-INF
           |- service.wsdl
  |- wsimport.bat
```

The wsimport.bat file looks like this:

```
wsimport -keep -d ../src/main/java -wsdlLocation ../src/resources/META-INF/service.wsdl
```

which was based on the Metro Guide example but without the -p option (http://metro.java.net/guide/Developing_client_application_with_locally_packaged_WSDL.html).  However, when I run the bat file, I get an endless loop of of the command being printed to the console. E.g.

```
C:\Devel\ClientProject>wsimport -keep -d ../src/main/java -wsdlLocation ../src/resources/META-INF/service.wsdl
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have tried using absolute paths (and rearranging the param order to no avail.  I still get the endless command console prints:

```
wsimport C:\Devel\ClientProject\src\resources\META-INF\service.wsdl -d C:\Devel\ClientProject\src\main\java -keep
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/problems-generating-client-using-local-wsdl-file#comment-812705

If using a .bat file to run the wsimport command, do not name it wsimport or you'll be in an endless recursive loop calling that file.

Also, "-wsdllocation" is case sensitive. "-wsdlLocation" will not work (although I've seen many examples of it during my searches).

This wsimport command generates the client code from the local WSDL and sets the "wsdlLocation" attribute on the Service class' @WebServiceClient annotation:

```
wsimport src/resources/META-INF/service.wsdl -keep -d src/main/java -wsdllocation META-INF/service.wsdl
```