# Generate webservice client when WSDL uses SOAP 1.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL file which I want to generate a webservice client from. The problem is that the WSDL I've gotten uses SOAP 1.2:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" [...]>
```

And

```
<wsoap12:operation soapAction="[...]" />
```

When I try to generate a client from this I only get the request/response Java beans.

If I on the other hand edit the WSDL to use SOAP 1.1 (and *nothing* else), everything generates beautifully, except that it will send SOAP 1.1 request instead of SOAP 1.2, and the server will yell at me to use 1.2 instead...

I generate the code using Spring Tool Suite on Windows 7 by right clicking the WSDLs and selecting "Web services > Generate client". All this have worked like a charm before, when we were using SOAP 1.1.

I've also tried to generate it with `wsimport` of the maven plugin `jaxws-maven-plugin` to no avail; it too generates only the beans, not the proxy.

Is there a way to get this to work? Or is there some way I can modify the generated `*ServiceProxy.java` classes for them to use SOAP 1.2 instead of 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at Metro.  That should support Soap 1.2.

Someone posted a reference to client gen using Metro here: [Generating Metro Client Using Local WSDL File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237027/generating-metro-client-using-local-wsdl-file)

Metro wsimport options:
http://metro.java.net/1.2/docs/wsimport.html

Comment: Metro was really nice to use, though I had tons of other problems because of 1.2 afterwards. Took a while to get through them all, but it worked out pretty well in the end. Thanks.